# RingCentral ERROR 503: The request could not be satisfied

Tags: c#, ringcentral, glip

We are trying to download attachments from RingCentral (Glip), however, we have noticed that the download URL has been changed during the last couple of days. We have tried using the Bearer Token with the new download URL to download the files, however, we have received an error with response code 503.

ERROR

503 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Generated by CloudFront (CloudFront)

Request URL

dl.mvp.devtest.ringcentral.com/file/105660426

Answer (score 1):

The only change necessary for the recent auth change is to add the Bearer Token to the URL. This can be seen in the update notice:

> **What do I need to do?**
>
> To eliminate or minimize the impact of this change, developers will need to modify their application to attach authentication credentials to all file download requests. See [downloading protected content](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/basics/media#downloading-protected-content) in the Media content section of the RingCentral Developer Guide.

https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/important-changes-to-how-team-messaging-files-are-downloaded-bb13c97b3c89

A 503 HTTP Status Code is a temporary sever-side error so there's generally nothing to be done on your end but the problem should go away on its own. If you cannot wait or it's taking a long time to resolve itself, please [create a support case](https://developers.ringcentral.com/support/create-case) so the team can communicate the status to you.

Here's [some information on 503 errors from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503):

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>
> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.
>
> Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded. This response should be used for temporary conditions and the Retry-After HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.
>
> Caching-related headers that are sent along with this response should be taken care of, as a 503 status is often a temporary condition and responses shouldn't usually be cached.